# Tracking multiple logins from the same user with Stormpath

Tags: rest, jwt, stormpath, multiple-login

I'm working on a mobile application that uses Stormpath on the server side for authentication and authorization. I need to support the same user signing in on more than one device, but I want to be able to keep track of it and limit it if I want to.

My application currently uses Stormpath to sign in the user using email/password or MDN/password and upon successful login returns a JWT token to use for API access to the server.

I'm thinking of the following approach:

- Keep a list of sessions in the user's account. Every time the user signs in, a new entry is added with the device_id and the JWT provided. When the user signs off, the entry is removed or marked inactive.
- When a user tries to sign in on another device, if I want to restrict to only one active device, I would set the other entry to disabled and expire the JWT so the application can detect it and require login again.
- If I wanted to restrict the user to a maximum of n sessions, I could just count the entries and force the user to sign off on one of the other sessions before allowing her/him to sign in on the new device

Is this a good approach? Is there a better way to do it? What are the issues with this method?

Answer (score 1):

I work at Stormpath on the mobile SDKs. You can use the access / refresh token feature that we have to accomplish this.

- Every time the user signs in, an access and refresh token are created. When the user signs off, the refresh token is deleted, as well as the access token.
- When a user tries to sign in on another device, if you want to restrict to only one active device, you can delete all of the other access & refresh tokens.
- If you wanted to restrict the user to a maximum of n sessions, I could just count the entries and force the user to delete one of the refresh tokens before allowing her/him to sign in on the new device. You would then go through the access tokens, and delete ones with a matching "rti" (refresh token ID)

Several notes about implementing this:

- If you're using a Stormpath Framework integration, the default is to verify an access token locally (instead of sending it to Stormpath to validate). This is because they have a signature that can be validated by the SDK. However, to log out a user, you'll either have to set this to remote validation, or use a short access token life (and use the refresh tokens to control each "session")
- Refresh tokens can't store "customData", so you'll have to maintain metadata about the refresh token in either the account's customData, or in your own database.
- Alternatively, you could "create" API Keys for each user, and use that instead of sessions for each user. You can use the API Key name or description attributes to keep track of where the user signed in from / etc.

Comment: Thanks Edward, this is pretty much in line with what I was thinking. 
I appreciate your confirming it.